# Parsing a string separated by Commas using MPLAB Compiler?

Tags: c

I am parsing a string separated by commas and printing the values but for some reason this code only prints the first value if I run it on MPLAB C Compiler. However, if I run this code on Codeblocks, it prints out all the values.

**MPLAB OUTPUT**

2

**CODEBLOCKS OUTPUT**

2

100

200

100

Code:

```
char somestr[] ="2,0100,0200,0100";
char *pt;
int a;
pt = strtok (somestr,",");
    while (pt != NULL) 
{

        a = atoi(pt);
        printf("%d\n", a);
        pt = strtok (NULL, ",");
    }
```

**I would like the output to be like this**

2

0100

0200

0100

So what is really going on ? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering how you got `0100` and `0200` (using the `%d` specifier, you should get `100` and `200`, [and you do](http://ideone.com/wS3hCm)), but by running this code, all the output should definitely be printed. The code seems fine. Possible reasons why this may not be the case:

- You have some more code that invokes undefined behavior and interferes with this piece of code;
- This is not the actual code you're compiling;
- The terminal or wherever the program prints after having been compiled by the MPLAB compiler has a bug or you just didn't notice that it should be scrolled;
- a compiler or standard library bug? *(very unlikely...)*

Edit: so you **want** the output to be zero-padded. For that, use the `%04d` format specifier when `printf()`ing the variable.

Comment: I am suspecting number 1 from the list but I am still unsure about what is going on.

Comment: Could it be from the somestr? Maybe MPLAB C Compiler uses different form?